# How can I subtract from arraylist some values ?

Tags: java, arraylist, subtraction

Here is an example:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> position = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> new_position = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Collections.copy(new_position, position);
    for (int j = 0; j < position.size(); j++) {

        new_position.get(j) -=4;
    }
```

I want to copy values and then from my new arraylist subtract 4. How can I make it ? 
I'm new in java. Also I've got an error such as: `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable`, it refers to `nowe_pozycje.get(j) -=4;`.

Comment: Get the value, subtract from it, and put it back. An `ArrayList` is not an array.

Comment: `subtract 4` means? what exactly you want to do? do you want to remove 4 elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to `get()` the value, change it, and then `set()` the new value:

```
for (int j = 0; j < position.size(); j++) {
    new_position.set(j, new_position.get(j) - 4);
}
```

An alternative solution could be to skip the whole copying of the list, and instead iterate through the original list, change each value as you go, and add them to the new `List`:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> new_position = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer i: position) {
    new_position.add(i - 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to subtract 4 from every element of ArrayList then:

```
ArrayList<Integer> position = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> new_position = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Collections.copy(new_position, position);
for (int j = 0; j < position.size(); j++) {
    new_position.set(j, (new_position.get(j) - 4)); //remove 4 from element value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int n : position) new_position.add(n-4);
```

You don't need to use Collection.copy().